# MessageBox doesn't close when I use KeyUp event

Tags: c#, messagebox, enter, keyup

My form has one textbox for input, listview for save.

User input number in textbox, and input enter, program check input number length and duplication

1. textbox KeyUp Event

   ```
   private void txb_MList_num_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
       {
           if (check_MList_dup())
           {
               lstv_MList.Items.Add(txb_MList_num.Text);
               allList.Add(txb_MList_num.Text);
               txb_MList_num.Text = "";
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. check_MList_dup()

   ```
   private bool check_MList_dup()
   {
       bool OK = true;
       if (txb_MList_num.TextLength < 11)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Input more text(length = 11)");
           return false;
       }
       else
       {
           for (int i = 0; i < allList.Count; i++)
               if (allList[i].Equals(txb_MList_num.Text))
               {
                   MessageBox.Show("It's duplication.");
                   return false;
               }
       }
       return OK;
   }
   ```

But User input enter for close MessageBox, program show MessageBox again, again...before using mouse.

I debug it use breakpoint, event is not occuer when MessageBox is showing.

But delete breakpoint, MessageBox is repeated.

I use `e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && this.Focused`

but `this.Focused` always return `false` .

How can I close MessageBox?

Comment: Show us how you create/open the messagebox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and use `txb_MList_num`[`.KeyDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx) event

As per MSDN:-

> "KeyDown event Occurs when a key is pressed while the control has focus."

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PreviewKeyDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.previewkeydown):

```
private void OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Enter))
    {
        // Do your staff here...
    }
}
```